# Issues while using Quotes in PHP

Tags: php, quotes

I have Learnt that Quotes doesn't matter in PHP.

But in the following code, if I try to use single quotes in `eval()`; I get error, on the other hand code works fine with Double Quotes.

```
$a = '2';
$b = '3';
$c = '$a+$b';
echo $c.'<br/>';
eval("\$c = \"$c\";");
//eval('\$c = \'$c\';');  //Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING
echo $c;
```

Comment: Who told you quotes don't matter?

Comment: Things inside single quotes aren't interpreted. Things inside double quotes are. quotes DO matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php) says that escape sequences are not expanded when using single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Quotes do matter ;-)

```
<?php

$color = "red";

echo "My car is $color"; // Outputs "My car is red"
echo 'My car is $color'; // Outputs "My car is $color"

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike double quotes, PHP does not parse variables in single quotes.

**Example:**

```
$name = 'John';
echo 'hello $name'; // hello $name
echo "hello $name"; // hello John
```

[More Information](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

---

FYI, it isn't good idea to use `eval` in production environment for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Using `eval` is a `bad idea` but if you are doing this for `learning purpose` then the correct way is

```
  eval("\$c = \$c;");
```

.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have one  ore doubt. May I know Why are we escaping $c with `backslash`.

Answer (score 0):

[don't use eval](https://www.google.com/search?q=eval%20is%20evil) and update your [string-quoting skills](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) here:

Answer (score 0):

The following example was lifted from: [The PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

```
<?php
echo 'this is a simple string';

echo 'You can also have embedded newlines in 
strings this way as it is
okay to do';

// Outputs: Arnold once said: "I'll be back"
echo 'Arnold once said: "I\'ll be back"';

// Outputs: You deleted C:\*.*?
echo 'You deleted C:\\*.*?';

// Outputs: You deleted C:\*.*?
echo 'You deleted C:\*.*?';

// Outputs: This will not expand: \n a newline
echo 'This will not expand: \n a newline';

// Outputs: Variables do not $expand $either
echo 'Variables do not $expand $either';
?>
```